# JQuery Ajax Form Submission is remaining static and I can't see why!

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

Might be easier to look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pkAGz/ and the `process.php` code is shown below:

```
<?php
//Retrieve form data. 
//GET - user submitted data using AJAX
//POST - in case user does not support javascript, we'll use POST instead
$name = ($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : $_POST['name'];
$email = ($_GET['email']) ?$_GET['email'] : $_POST['email'];

//flag to indicate which method it uses. If POST set it to 1
if ($_POST) $post=1;

//Simple server side validation for POST data, of course, 
//you should validate the email
if (!$name) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter a name.';

//if the errors array is empty, send the mail
if (!$errors) {

$name = $name[array_rand($name)];

$to = '$name <$name email adress if set>';   
//sender
$from = $name . ' <' . $email . '>';

//subject and the html message
$subject = 'Comment from ' . $name; 
$message = '
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head></head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr><td>Name</td><td>' . $name . '</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Email</td><td>' . $email . '</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>';

//send the mail
$result = sendmail($to, $subject, $message, $from);
//echo "\n\n$name has been nominated to make the tea!\n\n";
//echo "\n\nThey will also be notified by e-mail if you entered their address.\n\n";
//if POST was used, display the message straight away
if ($_POST) {
    if ($result) echo "\n\n$name has been nominated to make the tea!\n\nThey will also be notified by e-mail if you entered their address.\n\n";
    else echo 'Sorry, unexpected error. Please try again later';

//else if GET was used, return the boolean value so that 
//ajax script can react accordingly
//1 means success, 0 means failed
} else {
    echo $result;   
}

//if the errors array has values
} else {
//display the errors message
for ($i=0; $i<count($errors); $i++) echo $errors[$i] . '<br/>';
echo '<a href="index.php">Back</a>';
exit;
}


//Simple mail function with HTML header
function sendmail($to, $subject, $message, $from) {
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";

$result = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

if ($result) return 1;
else return 0;
}
?>
```

Once the AJAX request is working the next step is simply work around the code to send an e-mail to the person chosen if their e-mail address was entered - a bit stuck on how to do that as I want the e-mail field to remain optional.

Then obviously, I want to return the name of the person that was picked at random and that will be it!

Thanks,

Martin

Comment: I can't understand THE problem. If email is blank you just pick email from database or file, or output error or something... If you picked random person, just return it with your html response. That's it. $errors[count($errors)] - interesting, yet oddish approach to populate array. Why don't you define array before populating and then just do $array[] = 'new value'; ?

Comment: sorry if I am not clear, bascially what happens when you click the `submit` button is that the browser takes you to `process.php` instead of the output from `process.php` being shown on the index page that called it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Firebug for Firefox, or watch the console in Chrome/Safari. So you would have seen that you have a javascript error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: comment is not defined
```

So the script:

```
//cancel the submit button default behaviours
return false;
```

isn't executed and the form is posted normally.

Comment: Thanks, that was a silly error. After taking out the offending lines, the JS is throwing the alert caused by process.php returning 0 - any ideas?

Comment: Because your sendmail function probably returns 0. Is the email sent out? Perhaps your mail settings are not correct.

Comment: yeah, the mail definitely sends - I am receiving them but the error is still thrown for some reason.

Comment: but is your sendmail function returning 1 or 0?

Comment: not sure, trying to install firebug on chrome - I'm sure I already had it but it's not here and it's not installing....

Comment: On chrome you can choose Tools->Developer tools from your menu. You see your requests on the Network tab

Comment: not used the network tab before actually, it comes back as status 200, OK.